# django join three table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, mysql-python

Please, someone help me. i'm new to django. i have 3 table (products, product_images, product_prices) and product_images.product_id==products.id && product_prices.product_id==products.id. I want to join three tables using **products.id**. I've searched a lot, to solve my problem but failed. sorry my poor english. here is my code...

**models.py**

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
     id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
     product_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
     product_image = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'product_images'



class ProductPrice(models.Model):
     id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
     product_id = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
     market_price = models.FloatField()
     sale_price = models.FloatField()

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'product_prices'



class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    images = models.ForeignKey(ProductImage, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, to_field='product_id', 
    null=True, blank=True)
    prices = models.ForeignKey(ProductPrice, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, to_field='product_id', 
    null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'products'
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_products(request):
     products = Product.objects.select_related().values_list('title', 'images__product_image', 'prices__market_price')
     return HttpResponse(products.query)
```

**unexpected output**

```
SELECT 
     `products`.`title`, 
     `product_images`.`product_image`, 
     `product_prices`.`market_price` 
     FROM `products` 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_images` 
         ON (SELECT 
     `products`.`title`, 
     `product_images`.`product_image`, 
     `product_prices`.`market_price` 
     FROM `products` 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_images` 
         ON (`products`.`images_id` = `product_images`.`product_id`) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_prices` 
         ON (`products`.`prices_id` = `product_prices`.`product_id`) = `product_images`.`product_id`) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_prices` 
         ON (`products`.`prices_id` = `product_prices`.`product_id`)
```

i want to replace
**products.images_id** to **products.id**
and **products.prices_i**d to **products.id**

[image: see below image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you have defined `to_field='product_id'` in your models and that's what is used when joining so `image_id` is joined on `product_id`. The query is perfectly fine. You can't join on the `product.id`, because there is no relationship on the `id`.

Comment: #Borut, thanks for replaying. but my problem is products.image_id && products.price_id. i've no such column in my products table. so it generated error: (1054, "Unknown column 'products.images_id' in 'on clause'")

Comment: Sure you have. They are right there in the your Product model: `images` and `products`, which is translated to `images_id` and `products_id` in the database table. Either you have to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` or you have created some other issue due to which your model and actual table in the database mismatch. But the query is fine and corresponds to your models.